Cannot capture Win32 TraceLogging events
This is Microsoft's "Quick Start" example for the TraceLoggingProvider header:
#include <windows.h> // or <wdm.h> for kernel-mode.
#include <winmeta.h> // For event level definitions.
#include <TraceLoggingProvider.h>

TRACELOGGING_DEFINE_PROVIDER( // defines g_hProvider
    g_hProvider, // Name of the provider handle
    "MyCompany.MyComponent", // Human-readable name for the provider
    // {ce5fa4ea-ab00-5402-8b76-9f76ac858fb5}
    (0xce5fa4ea,0xab00,0x5402,0x8b,0x76,0x9f,0x76,0xac,0x85,0x8f,0xb5));

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) // or DriverEntry for kernel-mode.
{
    TraceLoggingRegister(g_hProvider);

    TraceLoggingWrite(
        g_hProvider,
        "MyEvent1",
        TraceLoggingLevel(WINEVENT_LEVEL_WARNING), // Levels defined in <winmeta.h>
        TraceLoggingKeyword(MyEventCategories), // Provider-defined categories
        TraceLoggingString(argv[0], "arg0"), // field name is "arg0"
        TraceLoggingInt32(argc)); // field name is implicitly "argc"

    TraceLoggingUnregister(g_hProvider);
    return 0;
}

I compiled and ran this code while capturing events with the tracelog tool, but no events where captured. Also tried capturing with wrl, also without success. What's wrong?
Compiler: MSBuild v143 build tools (Visual Studio 2022)
Capturing command: C:\"Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits"\10\bin\10.0.26100.0\x64\tracelog.exe -start TraceLogTest -f TraceLogTest.etl -guid #ce5fa4ea-ab00-5402-8b76-9f76ac858fb5
Stopping command: C:\"Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits"\10\bin\10.0.26100.0\x64\tracelog.exe -stop TraceLogTest

Do the function calls succeed? You should probably use a unique provider name and a unique GUID rather than re-using existing IDs, The documentation explains how best to generate a GUID.

Thanks for the suggestions. Yes, the function calls succeed. Generating a unique GUID from the provider name didn't solve my problem though.

I suggest you could refer to the sample: C/C++ TraceLogging Examples
